# Как убрать часть урла из $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

Tags: php

Извиняйте сразу, я php видел только в кино.
Есть задачка, я получаю адрес страницы через $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
На выходе имею что-то типа '/finance/cryptocurrency/page.html'
Мне нужно как-то убрать часть урла "/finance/" и положить ее в переменную
Понимаю, что задачка на основы php, но я нуб. Буду рад подсказке в решении

Comment: explode() вам в помощь

Comment: Спасибо, получилось